# How Import Google Analytics Data into S3 Bucket without Using AppFlow

Tags: amazon-s3, google-analytics-4, amazon-appflow

I want to import my google analytic data in S3 bucket. I want to know if its possible to import it without using Appflow. I don't have any problem using code.

Comment: Hi Shu,  Did you find any promising approaches regarding how best to import google analytics data into S3 without AppFlow?  Thanks!